# About sentence structure

Tags: sentence-construction

> The technology, **often so prescient it borders on creepy**, has made Chinese counterparts very profitable too.
> [China Tech: Those Who Control The Algorithms Control The Future](https://swiftheadline.com/china-tech-those-who-control-the-algorithms-control-the-future/)

I've never seen a sentence that includes this kind of structure. How can I understand it in grammar? Could you give another example?

Comment: It looks like an example of **whiz-deletion** to me: think of it as "The technology, *which is* often so prescient..."

Comment: I'd analyse it as an adjective phrase functioning as a supplement, a non-integrated, non-modifying element.

Answer (score 1):

I'd analyze the bolded text as a postpositive adjectival phrase (headed by the adjective "prescient"). It is not hard to come up with examples:

> The Grinch, **green with envy**, really hates Christmas.

> The white chess piece, **surrounded by black pieces**, can not move.

> The lion, **slowly approaching the gazelle**, is very careful.

Other interpretations (such as reduced relative clause) are also possible.

Comment: Postpositive implies that it's a modifier. But it isn't; it's a supplement, a non-integrated, non-modifying element.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for the comment. I consider it to be a modifier.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's the wrong analysis. The commas that surround it have been used deliberately to mark it as an adjunct -- more specifically a supplement, detached by intonation or punctuation from the rest of the clause. It's predicative in that it's related to a predicand, in this case "the technology", and thus is a 'predicative adjunct'.  If the writer had intended it to modify "the technology", they would have written it without commas so that it was integrated into the subject noun phrase.

Comment: @BillJ My interpretation is corrected and supported. For example, the Oxford English Grammar (section 5.8, "restrictive and non-restrictive modification") gives examples of "non-restrictive postmodifiers" modifying nominal phrases that they follow and surrounded by commas.

Comment: The whole point about 'non-restrictive' is that it is 'non-modifying'. It's the same with non-restrictive relative clauses: they too are supplements, not modifiers.

Comment: Further, supplements with the form of an AdjP, NP or PP do not combine with the noun to which they relate to form a syntactic unit. In your example the _lion, slowly approaching the gazelle_, for instance, is not a constituent, as evident from the commas that set the AdjP apart as a non-integrated expression, and thus a supplement not a modifier.

Comment: @BillJ I really don't know what else to say. I cited a reputable authority that supports my position. You seem to be suggesting that my interpretation is invalid because it doesn't satisfy the criteria of your interpretation; I don't find that argument persuasive. Perhaps we should leave it there, before the comments get too lengthy.

Comment: Of course, but please read my answer for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> *The technology,* [*often so prescient it borders on creepy,*] *has made*
> *Chinese counterparts very profitable too.*

The commas mark the bracketed adjective phrase as a supplement, a loosely attached expression set off by punctuation (and intonation) presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Supplements are not modifiers; rather, they refer to an 'anchor' -- in this case the anchor is the noun phrase "the technology". By virtue of not being integrated into the syntactic structure, supplements are necessarily semantically non-restrictive.

Supplements with the form of an adjective phrase, a noun phrase or a preposition phrase most often function as predicative adjuncts:

> *Bob,* [*angry because Joe has married his ex-wife Sally*]*, forces Joe's car off the road*. (adjective phrase)
>
> [*A proud teetotaller*], *John stuck to water while the others drank*
> *champagne.* (noun phrase)
>
> [*In a bad temper*]*, as usual, John walked on ahead of the main party.*
> (preposition phrase)

They are called predicative adjuncts because they are related to a predicand. For example, the adjective phrase "angry because Joe has married his ex-wife Sally" refers to "John". It can be compared to the predicative complement in *Bob was* [*angry because Joe has married his ex-wife Sally*].